# Finding segment bisectors in Poincare disc model

Tags: geometry, hyperbolic-geometry

Problems says:

> Given $2$ points $A,B$ find the bisector of segment $AB$.

(I hope I'm using correct terms, this was translated by myself. In the original text h-points,h-segment,h-bisector were used but I didn't find those in English literature)

Suppose one of the points is at the center of disc WLOG $A$

[image: disk model]

Text claims that line s which is a part of a circle that maps $B$ to $A$ through inversion is the bisector. I do understand that property of s but I don't understand how do we see that s bisects $AB$

Next picture shows how s in constructed
[image: circle inversion]

Can you explain why is s the bisector ?

Comment: Do you want justification of the text's claim that the bisector should be part of a circle that inverts $A$ to $B$? Or are you asking for proof that the geometric construction depicted gives that circle? Both? Neither? Something else? (Be sure to add context and/or clarifications to the body of the question. Comments are easily overlooked and may be hidden.)

Comment: @Blue I want justification on why does s bisect AB